# querystring in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

how to use querystring in asp.net.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what exactly query.string did in the language you refer to, but...

```
Request.QueryString["MyValue"];
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Good article realted to query string

[ASP.NET Client Side State Management - Query Strings](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2008/05/17/asp-net-client-side-state-management-query-strings.aspx)

[Passing variables between pages using QueryString](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/QueryString.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
Request.QueryString["StringValue"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
  <head runat="server">  
  <title>asp.net QueryString example: how to use QueryString</title>  
  </head>  
  <body>  
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  
    <div>  
    <h2 style="color:Navy">QueryString Example</h2>  
    <asp:HyperLink   
        ID="HyperLink1"  
        runat="server"  
        NavigateUrl="~/Image.aspx?ImageID=1&ImageName=Elephant"  
        Text="Test QueryString"  
        >  
    </asp:HyperLink>  
</div>  
</form>
```

you can also use button click event instead of page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {  
    string ID = Request.QueryString["ImageID"];  
    string Name = Request.QueryString["ImageName"];  
    Label1.Text = "ImageID: "+ ID;  
    Label2.Text = "Image name: "+ Name;  
    Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/"+Name+".jpg";  
}
```