# Checking value from previous form in ASP .NET, using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I writing a method that check values in the current page along with one value from the previouse page. I use jQuery for writing the check as following

```
function check_Finalized() {
        myTest();
        var Finalized_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        Finalized_value.type = "hidden";
        Finalized_value.name = "Finalized_value";

        if (((document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFinalized") != null) && (document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFinalized").value != "") && (document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlResponsibility").value=="2") &&document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_chkSD").value =="checked"))

        {
            // document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_chkSD").value =="checked") && 
            if (confirm("Remember to forward finalisation email to Study Director" + "\n" + " You are shortly to receive the email in outlook")) {
                Finalized_value.value = "OK";
            } else {
                Finalized_value.value = "No";
            }
        }
       else
            Finalized_value.value = "OK";

        document.forms[0].appendChild(Finalized_value);
    }
```

Where `(document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_chkSD").value =="checked"))` is the value checked from the previous page.

Comment: when you say page, has the page been reloaded between pages or is the previous page just hidden when you move to the next page?  If the former, then you cannot do this with jquery unless you ajax load in the next page whilst hiding the first page

Comment: The previouse page is just hidden when move into the next page.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. You want to check a value from a previous page. Are they completely separated pages, or like baby steps forms? How are you storing the value of it?

Comment: Ok, I've just realised you haven't exactly said what you're problem is - is it that the if is not working?  you may want to try adding some space between the && and the document.  Also if you look at your console (f12 and hit the console tab in your browser), are there any error?

Comment: The problem is I get the following error :0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference, since the (document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_chkSD").value =="checked")) is not present in the current page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

document.querySelectorAll("[id$=chkSD]")

Comment: I just relized that it is not getting any errors any more, however I still can't the right value. since the value I aquired is stored in the previous page/document. so document.querySelectorAll("[id$=chkSD]") looks into the current document, not the previous one :(

Comment: Are you accessing child page(content place holder value) in master page ? I think that is the case, just alert the output

Comment: The second page is a new page, so any method document.methods do not help. It must be something else that looks inside the application and fetch cashed data from the previous page.

Comment: The access data from different page, you can use query string or session variable in asp.net  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734020/querystring-in-asp-net